# How can we use SDA or SCL lines for I2C Addresses?

Tags: embedded, hardware, i2c

TMP102 chip( http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf ) can have multiple I2c slave addresses. It has an address pin called ADD0(**Section 5**) which can be used to select multiple addresses(**Section 7.3.4**). The logic level at that pin can be used to select a particular TMP102 slave device. According to **table 4**, 4 addresses are possible. I do understand that connecting the pin to high or low voltage will produce two different addresses. But the table mentions that we can use SDA and SCL pins for two different addresses. I am not sure how this works. Can anyone explain how can this be used and how can we use multiple TMP102 devices based on SDA and SCL pins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The logic level at that pin can be used to select a particular TMP102 slave device

That is not the purpose of ADD0 - it is a configuration pin, not a select pin. It is not used to *select* the device; I<sup>2</sup>C addresses are part of the data stream on SDA, there is no "*select*" pin as there is on SPI for example.

Rather, ADD0 is used to *define* the address of each device to one of four defined in Table 4. Those addresses being one of 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A or 0x4B depending on connection of ADD0 to GND, V+, SDA or SDL respectively.  Like so:

[image]

How the device determines the address is not revealed in the datasheet and you don't really need to know, but given:

[image]
<sub>Public domain image by Marcin Floryan from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C</sub>

at the *start condition* at the falling edge of SDA the following occurs:

```
ADDR ADD0 SDA SCL
0x48   0   v   1
0x49   1   v   1
0x4A   v   v   1   
0x4B   1   v   1
```

Then on the next falling edge SCL

```
ADDR ADD0 SDA SCL
0x48   0   0   v
0x49   1   0   v
0x4A   0   0   v   
0x4B   v   0   v
```

So it is possible with suitable sequential logic to latch the address by the end of the S phase and before B1 which is sufficient because the address match does not occur until B7, and all devices on the bus must listen for the address.

Comment: When will the logic level  be considered? In case of GND and V+, they are fixed. In case of SDA and SCL, they can be 0 or 1(logic levels). So will the level of SDA or SCL considered when it looks for 1bit of that address?

Comment: @omkarkale : You don't need to know to use the part, but I have added my guess at how it might be done.  However this is not an appropriate site for this question.  I have requested its migration.

Answer (score 1):

You connect ADD0 to SDA/SCL to get those other addresses. The table shows the address you get based on what ADD0 is connected to.